# Characterizing graph classes by the same forbidden set in two ways

Tags: graph-theory

Kuratowski and Wagner theorems characterize planar graphs in terms of forbidden homeomorphic subgraphs and forbidden minors, respectively. It turns out that both forbidden sets are the same: $\{K_5,K_{3,3}\}$.

Are there other examples where a forbidden set defines the same class of graphs in both ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One example that springs to mind: A (simple) graph is a forest iff it has no $K_3$ as a minor, and also iff it has no $K_3$ as a topological minor (homeomorphic subgraph).

More generally, if the forbidden graphs have maximum degree 3, there's no difference between minors and topological minors (see Proposition 1.7.4 in [Diestel's textbook](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/basic.html)).

Comment: Thank you! that prop. wasn't there in the 3rd edition.

Comment: It is Proposition 1.7.2 in the second edition.